# WilliamChart Highlight Bar on click & change y-axis labels

Tags: android, charts, bar-chart, highlight, axis-labels

I am using the WilliamChart library for BarChart in Android app. I want to implement highlight feature on bars when they are clicked. I looked into documentation and sample code but couldn't find how the sample app was using this feature. 
 
I tried to use barSet.getEntry(), it changes the bar color outside onClick, but it doesn't work inside onClick event. There must be something I'm missing. Here is code used to draw BarChart.

```
    mChart.setAxisBorderValues(0, 0, 50);

    final BarSet barSet = new BarSet();
    Bar bar;
    for (int i = 0; i < Xlabels.length; i++)
        barSet.addBar(new Bar(Xlabels[i], (float) earned[i]));
    barSet.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));

    mChart.setOnEntryClickListener(new OnEntryClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(int setIndex, int entryIndex, Rect rect) {

            // Change Bar Color Here

            barSet.getEntry(entryIndex).setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Earnings.this, R.color.white));
        }
    });

    mChart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {                
        }
    });

    mChart.addData(barSet);
    mChart.setBarSpacing(Tools.fromDpToPx(8));
    mChart.setBorderSpacing(0)
            .setXLabels(AxisController.LabelPosition.OUTSIDE)
            .setLabelsColor(Color.parseColor("#FF8E8A84"))
            .setXAxis(false)
            .setYAxis(false)
            .setLabelsFormat(new DecimalFormat("##'M'"));

    mChart.show(new Animation(1000).setEasing(new LinearEase()));
```

And, my second problem is that y-axis labels are appended with 'M' automatically in the end. How can I remove that or append different character in dynamic y-axis values?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by defining a [Tooltip](http://diogobernardino.github.io/WilliamChart/javadoc/com/db/chart/view/Tooltip.html) which will trigger on entry click. The good thing about using tooltips to do this is that it allows you to use transition animations (like in the sample application). Below is a snippet extracted from the mobile sample app:

```
    Tooltip tip = new Tooltip(mContext);
    tip.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f39c12"));

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        tip.setEnterAnimation(PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.ALPHA, 1)).setDuration(150);
        tip.setExitAnimation(PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.ALPHA,0)).setDuration(150);
    }

    mChart.setTooltips(tip);
```

Your second problem is only that you're apparently defining a label format that you apparently don't want. Here:

```
.setLabelsFormat(new DecimalFormat("##'M'"));
```